# how to dynamically set store dojo dgrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I want to set the store dynamically in a dGrid when I call a function and not when I declare.
Is it possible? In dataGrid I use

```
   gridId.setStore(newStore);
```

Is there something similar to it for dGrid in dojo?

I went through all the api's and documentation but still no result.

Comment: I am trying to implement the dgrid in a declarative manner so whenever I am trying to access the id its showing undefined.
Any solution on how to access the id or set the store when i am using it in declarative manner instead of programmatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dgrid follows the same pattern as Dijit of having central `set` and `get` methods rather than separate public `setFoo` and `getFoo` methods to call for every property.  So instead of `setStore(newStore)`, you call `set('store', newStore)`.  (In contrast, dojox DataGrid's APIs follow a pattern that has been deprecated since Dojo 1.4.)

This is covered in dgrid's [documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.15/doc/components/core-components/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid.md#method-summary) as well as in the [Grids and Stores tutorial](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/).

Comment: But i had to access the id using registry.byId() and then set('store', newStore) worked.
Thanks